# How to listen to android googlemaps geofence transitions

Tags: android-geofence

How can i make something happen when my location on a map enters and exits one of my application google map's fence. I cant seem to understand the tutorial of [google](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#RequestGeofences) regarding geofencing. And i cant find any other tutorial of this thing.

this are my code..

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
buildGeofence(14.728801, 120.961209, "Id_test", 500);
}

private void buildGeofence(double latitude ,double longitude, String requestId, int radius){

    int GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER = 1;
    LatLng geofencePoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    //int radius = 500;
    Geofence.Builder geofence = new Geofence.Builder();
    geofence.setCircularRegion(geofencePoint.latitude,geofencePoint.longitude, radius);
    geofence.setRequestId(requestId);
    geofence.setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE);
    geofence.setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER);
    geofence.setNotificationResponsiveness(0);
    geofence.build();


    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
    circleOptions.center(geofencePoint);
    circleOptions.radius(radius);
    circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
    circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);
    circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);
    mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dens,
To make something happen when you transition the Geofence you need to

1. Create an intent for Geofence transitions.
2. Create a GeofencingRequest.
3. Add the intent, GeofenceingRequest, and GoogleApiClient to the LocationServices.GeofencingApi API.
4. Handle the intent.

The code you have written so far will create a geofence and a circle on the map, but it will not yet do anything when the fence is transitioned.
In the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#RequestGeofences) you linked, you successfully created a geofence, but now you need to follow some of the other steps. Make sure you follow the steps in "Specify geofences and initial triggers", "Define an Intent for geofence transitions", and "Add geofences". This should complete steps 1, 2, and 3 that I listed above. One you have those steps working, try the section "Handle Geofence Transitions", which will complete step 4 that I listed above.

I hope this helps you!

P.S.: Since I see you are adding circles to the map, you may quickly discover you need a way to keep track of these circles in order to correctly add and remove them for each geofence. There is a short blog post [here](http://blog.brendanlacanette.com/2015/06/problem-there-is-no-native-way-to-add.html) that discusses how to do this.

Comment: But i want to do something on mainUI, i dont want to create a new intent and start a new service everytime?  cant we just set like some kind of OnGeofenceTransitionListener ? i want to do stuff on my map when people are close to the geofence

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea You will not be able to just use mainUI. Geofences use a pending intent, which means it waits for a specific action to happen before sending out the intent. In this case, it waits for a fence to be transitioned. These things need to happen in the background of the app, hence why you cannot use the UI thread. You can still do stuff on your map when people are close to the geofence, but you'll need to do it like [this.](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#RequestGeofences)